# RSpec rails mailer testing with accented character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, actionmailer

I'm trying to make a test for a Rails Mailer and when the string that I'm trying to match have some special characters or accents it always breaks.

My test:

```
RSpec.describe UsersMailer, :type => :mailer do

  let(:mail) { UsersMailer.create(@user) }

  it 'includes first_name' do
    expect(mail.body.encoded).to match("#{HTMLEntities.new.encode('Félix', :named)}")
  end

end
```

My email view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <%= "#{HTMLEntities.new.encode(@user.first_name, :named)}" %>
</body>
</html>
```

The differences between them:

test: `F&eacute;lix`

view: `F&amp;eacute;lix`

When I do it without HTMLEntities, my differences are:

test: `Félix`

view: `F=C3=A9lix`

I'm using Rails 4.2.rc1, don't know if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Just added a html_safe to my email view:

```
<%= "#{HTMLEntities.new.encode(@user.first_name, :named).html_safe}" %>
```

Was forgetting that.